# Vuex and form handling using v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm following the official vuex tutorial for vuex form handling: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html. I basically copy pasted their suggested implementation of **Two-way Computed Property** at the bottom, still I get an error saying that it cannot read property 'name' of undefined:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

found in

---> <CustomForm> at src/components/Form.vue
       <Register> at src/views/Register.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Form.vue:

```
<custom-input title="Name" v-model="name" placeholder="Name" required />
```

```
computed: {
    name: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.form.name
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('updateForm', ('name', value))
      }
    }
```

I tried to `console.log(this.$store.state.form.name)` before the return statement in the get function but nothing prints so

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a mutation that can update any value on your `state.form` object, then I'd do something like this.

In the mutation, use the key to assign the value to the right property

```js
  mutations: {
    updateForm (state, {key, value}) {
      state.form[key] = value;
    }
  }
```

And in the commit, use an object as the payload that has a key and value parameters

```js
computed: {
    name: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.form.name
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('updateForm', {key:'name', value});
      }
    }
```

Comment: My mutation looks like this: `updateForm: (state, key, value) => ({ ...state.form, [key]: value })`. I wanted to make it reusable for every input field and I am not sure that it works, so good point! This is however not related to my question, I can comment out the set function inside Form.vue and still get the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that, you can pass **only one** payload parameter. See the answer (2nd part) for how to use multiple parameters in the payload.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will use your suggested approach instead!

Comment: updated answer to only include the the relevant portion of answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can use mapFields to enable to way data binding
      computed: {
        ...mapFields({
          firstName: 'form.name',
          lastName: 'form.lastName',
          phoneNumber: 'form.phoneNumber',
          emailAddress: 'form.emailAddress'
        }),
      },
```

Add this to your mutations
import { updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields';

```
There is no need to add mutations to update the state this this done directly and using v-model you can bind these properties.
```

Comment: This package is life and time saver. 
I am using in Nuxt project. Made me happy as I have over 45 forms in the project. 
Thanks